# use multiprocessing to implement a function in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using a function that take too much time to finish since it takes a large input and use two nested for loops .

The code of the function :

```
def transform(self, X):
        global brands
        result=[]
        for x in X:
            index=0
            count=0
            for brand in brands:
                all_matches= re.findall(re.escape(brand), x,flags=re.I)
                count_all_match=len(all_matches)
                if(count_all_match>count):
                    count=count_all_match
                    index=brands.index(brand)

            result.append([index])
        return np.array(result)
```

So how to change the code of this function so that it uses multiprocessing in order to optimize the running time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the use of `self` in the method `transform`. So i made a common function.

```
import re
import numpy as np

from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def transformer(x):

    global brands

    index = 0
    count = 0

    for brand in brands:

        all_matches = re.findall(re.escape(brand), x, flags=re.I)

        count_all_match = len(all_matches)

        if count_all_match > count:

            count = count_all_match

            index = brands.index(brand)

    return [index]

def transform(X):

    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        result = executor.map(transformer, X)

    return np.array(list(result))
```

Comment: let's say brands=["a","b","c"] and i want to see the result of transform(["amine","mejri"]) .Why i get with my initial function: array([[0],[0]]) while i get with your function using multiprocess :array(<generator object result_iterator at 0x10e8944b0>, dtype=object).
I should see the same result ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to transform the generator to list. I have update the code.